# Sidebar text widget and duplicate content

Tags: seo, wordpress, duplicate-content

Is a text sidebar widget OK with SEO point of view? This widget has a 100 words text and its shown on every page. I am concerned about duplicate content issue.

I have a website that lists upcoming events and another website where I have my product catalog. For some reasons they can't be on the same website, to send the visitors to second website I have set up a text widget with an introduction and link.

Answer (score 1):

In SEO point of view, there is no risk to have a widget with the same text on all pages. Search engines like Google are capable of detecting that it's not the main content of each page.

In general, duplicate content issues are generated by duplicating the main content of a page (not header, footer or a sidebar).

Comment: Great relief hearing that.Thanks. I also have many widgets implemented on each page, but there are different widgets for different categories.